# Gatsby createSchemaCustomization add custom field to every node

Tags: plugins, graphql, gatsby

I'm working on a gatsby plugin for other gatsby front-ends which is retrieveing Contentful data using a graphql.
I'm extending the `createSchemaCustomization` API because I would like to add a new field (say `contentful_id`) field to each node.

Graphql allows to update the query by the visitor pattern so I attach the `contentful_id` field to every graphql node, and in the plugin `gatsby-node.js` I was adding this resolver (`setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType` but it's been deprecated) to this field so that if the graphql node couldn't find the `contentful_id`, it wouldn't blow up.

```
exports.setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType = () => {
  return {
    contentful_id: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (source) => {
        return source.contentful_id || '';
      },
    },
  };
};
```

Furthermore, I don't know how many nodes each gatsby front-end is generating in their own pages.

What I would like to get to is the following
For all types generated in each gatsby front-end, add a new String field called `contentful_id`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a Gatsby plugin which is retrieving Contentful data using GraphQL.

What you're building is called a [source plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-a-source-plugin/).

What typically happens is that you will implement the Gatsby `sourceNodes` API. Here's an example adapted from [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#sourceNodes):

```js
// first, you'll need to source from Contentful
const { getContentfulNode, getContentfulId } = require("./get-contentful-node.js")

exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  const nodeData = getContentfulNode()
  const contentfulId = getContenfulId()

  const node = {
    ...nodeData,
    contentful_id // this is where you add your field to the node
    // node metadata
    id: createNodeId(`my-data-${myData.key}`),
    parent: null,
    children: [],
    internal: {
      type: `MyNodeType`,
      mediaType: `text/html`,
      content: JSON.stringify(nodeData),
      contentDigest: createContentDigest(myData)
    }
  }

  const node = Object.assign({}, myData, nodeMeta)
  createNode(node)
}
```

If you *already* sourced the nodes but want to add an extra field to them outside of *sourceNodes*, I would use the [`onCreateNode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreateNode) API. You can check if the node is of type `ContentfulNode` (for example), and add a field to it if it is.